# Linux WiFi Hotspot GUI shows Not Running when I click on CREATE. Why?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, wifi-hotspot

I am using `Manjaro` as my OS and I had installed Linux-wifi-hostpot through https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot

In terminal, it showed that the transaction finished successfully, but when I opened its GUI and clicked on **Create Hotspot**, it threw *Command not found or exited with error status* in the terminal and it still said *Not Running* in the GUI.

It says `Your adapter can not be a station(i.e. connected) and an AP at the same time.`

What is its possible cause and appropriate solution?

Comment: `What is its possible cause` - Perhaps you're attempting to use your wifi device as a client (station?) and an AP at the same time. `appropriate solution` disable the wifi **client** setting for you adapter

Comment: Can you add as text **not as screenshot** the output of this command: `/sbin/iw list | sed -E -n '/^\tvalid interface combinations:/,/^\t[^\t]/p'`? (it tells about the wireless NIC capabilities). Not that's it's strictly necessary for the problem, but this might help to know what further options are available.

Comment: This is the output for the ```/sbin/iw list``` command. is in the following link. 
https://anotepad.com/note/read/2ppdxc5w

Comment: `interface combinations are not supported`, so there are no `valid interface combinations` entries at all. Indeed there's no other option than doing what JaromandaX wrote. 3 antennas but 0 combo. What a strange device.